# change values into missing in KNIME

Tags: nan, missing-data, imputation, knime

I have a dataset in which I have N/A for each missing value, how can I change it into an actual missing value, inside the column itself.
I've been trying with the Rule Engine node but it just doesn't work..
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Rule nodes will not work, but if you use a [**String Manipulation**](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.stringmanipulation.StringManipulationNodeFactory): `toNull(regexReplace($x$, "^N/A$", ""))` or a [**Java Snippet**](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.jsnippet.JavaSnippetNodeFactory) node (even simple): `out_x = "N/A".equals(c_x) ? null : c_x;` it is not very hard to replace that value with `null`, which KNIME will interpret in these cases as missing values.

Edit: I should add that the first option (with String Manipulation) will also replace the empty String to missing value and the regex's `^` means start of the String, `$` end of the String. In case you would need special characters, you might also need `\\Q`/`\\E` in order to avoid escaping parts. I would recommend the simpler Java Snippet solution though it might be scary at first sight.